# The value of the 153 large fish in John 21:11?

Tags: john

I have often wondered if the large catch of fish in [John 21:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2021:11&version=NET) just prior to Jesus' intimate discussion with Peter might have been a "test" or "challenge" to Peter as Jesus urged him to feed and tend the sheep.  Since it appears that Peter, following his three denials of Jesus, had returned to fishing is it plausible that this large catch would test Peter's allegiance by seeing the lucrative possibilities that lie on the shore before him?

How much would 153 large fish have sold for in the open market of that day?  Perhaps this was going through Peter's mind as he interacted with the risen Christ (weighing the options of returning to service or remaining a fisherman)?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) Be sure to [properly cite the text](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/810/423) you're asking about. The chapter and verse numbers do not always line up between the Hebrew, Greek, and English texts. I've gone ahead and edited this one for you.

Comment: Similar, but on closer inspection, different question: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/890/what-is-the-significance-of-153-fish

Answer (score 5):

### Difficulty in Determining Value

Apparently when it comes to ancient fishing and pricing, there is little to go by. One source referring to a different region of the Roman Empire (the Black Sea area) states of "epigraphic evidence" that "with one exception, we lack
evidence for a specific price charged for a definable quantity of salt-fish or
volume of fish sauce."<sup>1</sup> On the same page is mentioned one piece of evidence (probably the "one exception") that gives pricing information in the Roman world, but it is *almost three centuries after* Christ.<sup>2</sup>

As such, it is not very useful, especially since pricing was by weight, not number. It was probably not like the picture of fish in a net on page 193 of [this book](http://www.academia.edu/952627/Fishing_in_the_Roman_World), as the fish are really quite small. The Bible tells us the size of the fish here were μεγάλων ("large"), enough that the 153 of them together they could not haul into the boat itself (v.6), but could get it to shore (v.8, 11). Seven men were on the boat (v.2), but there is more than just manpower involved in trying to counter-balance a boat to haul in a net full of fish. But the actual weight is still unknown, as the size of the net is unknown, and "large" is a very non-descriptive term for weight (in many contexts a 12-24 inch fish might be large, but not as large as 36+ inches).

**As such, there are just too many unknowns to "value" the fish here.** It was probably of a reasonably good value for a haul of fish in that day, but too little is known to be sure.

### *Value* is Probably the Wrong Focus

It is unlikely the value of these particular fish were a temptation to Peter. This is because the text would seem to point to them being a symbol and reminder of Christ's promise to Peter. Without Jesus telling them to cast to the other side at that moment (v.6), they would have remained without fish (v.5). The whole experience was reminiscent of Christ's earlier meeting with Peter (Luke 5:4-8), when Peter recognized his own weakness (5:8), but Christ promised to make Peter the fisher of men (5:10).

Now Jesus is calling Peter to that task. So when Jesus asks if Peter loves Him more than τούτων ("these") in v.15—a reference that is ambiguous in Greek gender, and so could be masculine (referring to the other men there) or neuter (referring to the fish)—I believe it is a reference to the fish, but not specifically these fish, nor their value, but rather the whole concept of "fishing" that was Peter's life prior to meeting Christ.

Will Peter give that up for love of Christ to "feed" His flock (vv.15-19)? Especially when considering that fishing may only be productive and lucrative if Christ is blessing Peter doing it (as evidenced in this story here); and the implication of Christ's commands are that He would not be blessing that life, but the one He was calling Peter to partake of—feeding Christ's people.

---

**NOTES**

<sup>1</sup> Tønnes Bekker-Nielsen, ed., *Ancient Fishing and Fish Processing in the Black Sea Region* (Aarhus: Aarhus University Press, 2005), 43. (http://library.umac.mo/ebooks/b28050216.pdf accessed 5-2-2014)

<sup>2</sup> That evidence is [Diocletian's "Edict of Maximum Prices"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edict_on_Maximum_Prices) which is from AD 301. The Edict [is discussed in an accessible article](http://www.academia.edu/3726129/_with_dr._L.E._Tacoma_The_value_of_labour_Diocletians_Prices_Edict), but for purposes here a summary of prices is laid out well [here](http://ancientcoinsforeducation.org/content/view/79/98/). In that summary, pricing is in "*Denarii communes*" which the source notes "were not actually silver *denariias* we usually think of when discussing ancient Roman coinage" but instead "were notational currency." Given that, "one libra" of fish (with "1 libra=326 grams or just under pound") were priced as such:

```
fresh-water fish were 12 (8 for 2nd quality)
salt-water fish were 25 (16 for 2nd quality)
```

So we can see a near double price for salt-water fish. That document notes a general laborer made about 25 a day, most skilled positions 50, so about a pound of fish could *maximum* be anywhere from half to a whole day's wages for the *maximum* of wages for lower to middle class type workers during the beginning of the 4th century. *Maximum* because that was what the edict was prescribing, the *most* that could be charged/paid.

Answer (score 0):

The "153 large fish in John 21:11" is not about a test or the open market. Every NT Scripture must align with the Torah and TaNaKh. This is what the Bereans were doing with Paul's teachings.

There are seven key harvests mentioned in the Bible: barley, wheat, grapes, olive, pomegranates, figs, date, and more. Each harvest is symbolic of a type of believer. The first harvest is that of the barley: Christians who are filled with the Holy Spirit, the ones who have eyes to see and ears to hear, they are the ones who are the first to perceive what God is doing in any particular spiritual season.  They are the ones who do not fall into the trap of spiritual slumber. They are the voices keeping the church spiritually awake with their spirit-filled messages.

**The 153 are symbolic of the harvest of overcomers also called the first-fruits who make the lump holy, first-born high priests, the Remnant, the first-born, the 144,000, the voice crying at midnight in Matthew 25, the holy ones, the Melchizedek, the barley harvest, the Man-Child.**

### This aligns with the pattern of Romans 11:16 "Now if the firstfruit is holy, also the lump; and if the root is holy, also the branches."

I am posting some excerpts from Doug Fortune's blog:

153 = the removal of the mature sons from out of the sea of humanity and the carnal church systems and onto the EARTH. Some have previously described this event as the “rapture.” Now, we see that it could well represent the EMERGENCE of the BRIDE.

The fish are LARGE. This means they are fully-grown. This could indicate that this group of 153rd is mature adults, grown-up sons (the MANCHILD, the OVERCOMERS). This could also be why Jesus may have known the generation of His return, but not exactly when the Body would grow up.

Therefore, we understand that on this day Jesus was not teaching them how to be better fishermen; and they knew that also. He was teaching them how to CATCH HUMANS AND TURN THESE BELOVED people OF GOD BACK TO HIM. 
WHY THE EXACT NUMBER OF FISH....153?

153 fish = TOTALITY OF THOSE BROUGHT INTO KINGDOM.

http://www.dougfortune.org/a308.htm

I hope that his answers your question.

Comment: That answer sound more like a rhetorical answer than a hermeneutical answer.  There is nothing in the TEXT that identifies seven types of believer.  Certainly the parable of the harvest mentions four types of person (Matthew 13:1-23, Mark 4:1-20, and Luke 8:4-15), some lost, some saved and Rev 14 mentions two types of harvest - wheat and grapes but that is as far as the TEXT allows. This site is about understanding what the text says not preaching idioms.

Answer (score -1):

When I was out on a fishing boat on the Sea of Galilee. We threw the nets on the left side of the boat and didn’t catch any fish. So... we threw them on the right side and caught fish.

The boat hands were amazed and our tour guide says he’s been giving tours for 20 years and has never seen a fish caught.

After that, we started talking about the 153 and we started getting into geometria. The Hebrew words ‘I am God’ using Elohim (the plural) all add up to 153.

Each Hebrew letter represents a number. A is 1 b is 2 etc. when the phrase I am god is calculated it equals 153. Our tour guide was skeptical, as he is a Jew and doesn’t believe the New Testaments is divinely authored, so he immediately calculated it out when we got back to the bus. He’s still amazed.

Comment: Hi Spencer! Welcome to the community! I like your anecdotal experience with fishing. However, would it trouble you to make your answer more aligned to what the question is asking? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It is implied that it was a valuable catch even though the money value can not be specifically determined! Also, it is clear that Jesus could have made them all economically comfortable to say the least just by showing them where the fish were from day to day, but that is of temporary value and was not God’s divine plan for them! They were being made into Fishers of Men which is of far greater value and importance!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).